# In kendo dataviz chart local data binding , JSON data value was spilted?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I create a Column chart using Kendo ui dataviz.
 In my program, i am going to bind the local Javascript Array variable data to chart datasource.
 The JSON data was spilted like "3""9""6" for "396".
 I dont know why it happened.  My Source code is given blow. Please check it and Please give the solution.

**Source:**

```
/**************Variable Declaration**********************************/
var eligibilityData = new Array();
eligibilityData = {
    mem_status: {
        a: 396, b: "56", c: "1125", d: "8423"
    }
};

/**************Create Chart**********************************/
function createBarChart(eligibilityData) {
    /****** Issue: A value is 396 but it spilted into "3","9","6"************/
    $("#Chart1").kendoChart({
        theme         : $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
        dataSource    : {
            data: JSON.stringify(eligibilityData.mem_status.a),
        },
        seriesDefaults: { type: "column", },
        series        : [
            { field: "a", name : "A" }
        ],
        tooltip       : { visible: true, },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Local data should be passed as an array. No need to call JSON.stringify

```
data: [eligibilityData.mem_status]
```

See: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-data-Array

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` does not do what you expect. What you sentence really does is:

1. It gets the `number` 396 and converts it to a `string`.
2. Converts a `string` into an `array` of one character per element.

Not sure about the way you define the `DataSource` (why you want a `DataSource` with only one element) but if that is really what you want, you might try:

```
dataSource    : {
    data: [eligibilityData.mem_status.a]
},
```

or

```
dataSource    : {
    data: [eligibilityData.mem_status]
},
```